# Swift JSON validation fails this data from my web api, I do not know why

Tags: json, swift, api, validation

Here is the swift code

```
if JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(JSONData) {
   print (":Valid json")
} else {
   let JSONstring = NSString(data: JSONData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
   print(JSONstring)
}
```

which results in the 'else' part being executed, and outputs the JSON data converted to a string as follows:

`Optional("[{\"nPropertyID\":4,\"sAddress_1\":\"11 Some street\",\"sAddress_2\":\"Some Road\",\"sAddress_3\":\"Toytown\",\"sPostcode\":\"AB1 9XX\",\"dPurchaseCost\":9999.99,\"dtPurchaseDate\":\"2012-10-23T00:00:00\"}]")`

Comment: What is `JSONData`? And try not to use capitalise names of variables.

Comment: Does it matter? You can still use jsonObject(with:) to deserialise it, `try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [[String: Any]]`

Comment: Well, what's the point of the JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject if it gives wrong results? Plenty of people recommend using it. What I would like to know is: is there anything actually wrong with the json string?

Comment: For that we need to see this json string.

Comment: You're seeing it.  It's in the original question.

Comment: Here it is from fiddler.    "[{\"nPropertyID\":4,\"sAddress_1\":\"11 Welch House\",\"sAddress_2\":\"Beaconsfield Road\",\"sAddress_3\":\"Enfield\",\"sPostcode\":\"EN3 6UX\",\"dPurchaseCost\":88000.00,\"dtPurchaseDate\":\"2012-10-23T00:00:00\"}]"

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple documentation you can't use `isValidJSONObject` with `Data` or `String` objects (even if the input parameter is of type `Any`):

> Returns **YES** if the given object can be converted to JSON data, NO
>   otherwise. The object must have the following properties:
>
> - Top level object is an **NSArray** or **NSDictionary**
> - All objects are NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull
> - All dictionary keys are NSStrings
> - NSNumbers are not NaN or infinity

Instead you can use:

```
let jsonStr = "[{\"nPropertyID\":4,\"sAddress_1\":\"11 Welch House\",\"sAddress_2\":\"Beaconsfield Road\",\"sAddress_3\":\"Enfield\",\"sPostcode\":\"EN3 6UX\",\"dPurchaseCost\":88000.00,\"dtPurchaseDate\":\"2012-10-23T00:00:00\"}]"

if let jsonDataToVerify = jsonStr.data(using: .utf8)
{
    do {
        _ = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonDataToVerify)
        print("JSON is valid.")
    } catch {
        print("Error deserializing JSON: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

As suggested [here](http://blog.ericd.net/2018/01/29/swift-checking-if-a-string-is-valid-json/).